# how get destructor called for derived object from Gtk::Window

Tags: c++, destructor, gtkmm

I want to derive from `Gtk::Window` and want to create a stand alone window from that object. If the user closes that window, how can I achieve that the destructor of my derived object will be called.

I want to close it in the moment the window is destroyed by user. I tried to do it inside the "on_signal_delete" handler, but that results in segfault.

Currently my code did never call the destructor of the stand alone window!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <gtkmm.h>


class ExampleWindow : public Gtk::Window
{
    protected:

        //Child widgets:
        Gtk::Box m_VBox; 
        Gtk::Label m_Label1;
        std::string mytext;

    public:
        ExampleWindow(const std::string& text_):
            m_VBox{ Gtk::ORIENTATION_VERTICAL }
            ,m_Label1{ text_ }
            ,mytext{ text_ }
        {
            set_title("Example");
            set_border_width(10);
            set_default_size(400, 200);

            add(m_VBox);

            m_VBox.pack_start( m_Label1 );

            show_all_children();
        }

        virtual ~ExampleWindow()
        {
            // Not called for the stand alone win while closing it. How to achieve that?
            std::cout << "Destructor called for " << mytext << std::endl;
        }

        bool on_delete_event( GdkEventAny* ) override
        {
            std::cout << "sig on delete called"  << mytext << std::endl;
            // free( this ); // that results in segfault
            return true;
        }


};  


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    auto app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv, "some.base");

    ExampleWindow window{ "First Window" };

    // Create the same window as free window ( toplevel )

    ExampleWindow* win2 = new ExampleWindow("Stand Alone Win");

    win2->show();   // How can I desruct this window, if a user closes it?

    //Shows the window and returns when it is closed.
    return app->run(window);
}
```

EDIT: As comming up discussion from comments why it is not possible to not use `new` I provide this more complicated example to show that my real world application has to create the new windows from a signal handler inside gtk. So there is a need to create the objects on demand.

Full example which can create new windows on demand:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <gtkmm.h>


class ExampleWindow : public Gtk::Window
{
    protected:

        //Child widgets:
        Gtk::Box m_VBox;
        Gtk::Button m_button;
        std::string mytext;

    public:
        ExampleWindow(const std::string& text_):
            m_VBox{ Gtk::ORIENTATION_VERTICAL }
        ,m_button{ text_ }
        ,mytext{ text_ }
        {
            set_title("Example");
            set_border_width(10);
            set_default_size(400, 200);

            add(m_VBox);

            m_VBox.pack_start( m_button );
            m_button.signal_clicked().connect(sigc::mem_fun(this,&ExampleWindow::on_clicked));

            show_all_children();
        }   

        void on_clicked()
        {   
            ExampleWindow* win2 = new ExampleWindow("Stand Alone Win");
            win2->show();   // How can I desruct this window, if a user closes it?
        }


        virtual ~ExampleWindow()
        {
            // Not called for the stand alone win while closing it. How to achieve that?
            std::cout << "Destructor called for " << mytext << std::endl;
        }

        bool on_delete_event( GdkEventAny* ) override
        {
            std::cout << "sighandler on_delete called"  << mytext << std::endl;
            //delete this; // results in segfault
            return false;
        }

};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    auto app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv, "some.base");

    ExampleWindow window{ "Press to create new win" };

    //Shows the window and returns when it is closed.
    return app->run(window);
}
```

The question is still: Where can I hook into the signal handlers to `free` the dynamically created top level windows.

Answer (score -1):

You dynamically allocate `win2` but you never free the memory afterwards.

Call `delete` on `win2` after `Gtk::Application::run()` returns:

```cpp
delete win2;
```

#### Edit, after a discussion in the comments of this answer

Instead of dynamically allocating your pointer in `ExampleWindow::on_clicked()`, showing it and then forgetting about it, you should have some sort of a global registry, e.g. an array, of created windows that you can track and destroy when required. Coming up with a design on how to do this is not in scope of the original question so I won't suggest anything more concrete here. You can then even avoid having the dynamic allocation, as it was also suggested below.

Comment: Sorry for not beeing precise enough! I want to delete/free the win2 at the moment when the window was closed by the user.

Comment: If possible you can just avoid dynamic allocation, i.e. not use new.

Comment: I want create as many new top level windows as the user wants to create. So I see no chance to do it without allocating the window manually. In the "real world" application the user can create new views as often it likes to do that.

Comment: What's the difference between you allocating it on main stack and creating a pointer which you'll have to pass around and maintain?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with GTK and how you program for it, but unfortunately you will never get the destructor to be called for a dynamically allocated object unless you free the memory. I'm with @Spidey on this one - what forces you to use pointers? Can't you just allocated it on the stack and pass it's address to `Gtk::Application::run()`?

Comment: Because I am not running on main stack in the signal handler where the user creates it. The user should be able to create the new window from some widget, e.g. by pressing a button. So we are sitting on the sighandler of the button.

Comment: In this case, expanding the minimal example you've provided would help: the code that gets executed when that "make me a window" event occurs would be a good first step.

Comment: I added a new additional example... nothing really different. As I said: Simply create windows on demand...